# Is it possible to make some action in a new Spring trascation before a user stars work with it?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-transactions

I have Spring Boot JPA application.

An application user asks a new transaction from time to time.

I'd like to execute some action on a db connection that is related with the transaction just BEFORE the use can work with that transaction.

"Just BEFORE" means the action has been completed before the first statement of a method annotated with @Transactional is executed.

The action is an execution of a stored procedure with params depend on the current application user.

Application uses work with DB under a technical account.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please give some example, even as a pseudocode. It's hard to understand what you mean by "just before". "Asking for new transaction" is not much clearer, either.

Comment: You can create a repo method to run your proc using `@Query`.  Then just call that to start with in your `@Transactional` method. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-native

Comment: @Wojciech Marciniak, I added  an explanation  what "Just before" means.

Answer (score 0):

- First solution:

Put all in `@Transacional` annotated method, where your pre-transaction, however this may sound weird, part goes first.

This first part may perform any action and maybe throw en exception if anything goes wrong, thus forcing the transaction to roll back. This may be a `@Repository` method, a `@Query` annotated one if needed (like [Josh Pospisil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11552945/josh-pospisil) suggests) or whatever.

- Second solution (I would prefer):

Put 3 method calls in your `@RestController`'s method: first - determining the user, second - performing your *pre-transactional* action using this user's data, third - the actual `@Transacional` method doing the job.

Comment: Thank you @WojciechMarciniak  for your suggestions. We have implemented more than a hundred controllers. So insertion of code in each controller  or transactional method is an evident but not a good solution. I'll try to find more simple one without much coding.